# How to separate multiple arrays returned by fetching a database?

Tags: php, database, arrays, pdo

I'm using PDO's FETCH_ASSOC to get data from a database.
Unfortunately, it creates a new array for every row.

```
Array (
  key => value
)

Array (
  key2 => value2
)
```

Is there a way to separate the arrays? I want to create an array of arrays, but I know how to do that if I will be able to separate the arrays.

```
$q = $DBH->query($sql) or die("failed!");
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($r = $q->fetch()){
    print_r($r);
}
```

EDIT:
This is what I wan't the big array to look like:
`Array(  [0] => Array(...), [1] => Array(...)  ...  [n] => Array(...)  )`

Comment: Could fetchAll be used instead? http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php Ex 5 May be worth looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did mean something like this?

edit:

```
$result = $q->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

from:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php